# Read cookie with a different domain BE/FE

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch, cross-domain

I have a project where the frontend and backend it's not allowed in the same domain, from the backend I'm trying to set a cookie in the frontend, but when I try to access the cookie via javascript (document.cookie) the cookie doesn't appear, but when I check the cookies in the browser the cookies are there, but the browser discriminates by the domain.

[Image cookies in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBmxt.png)

Comment: *"discriminates by the domain"* . That is a security feature. You don't want every site you go to sifting through all your cookies looking for the really good chocolate chips

Comment: This is about SOP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy